# Homomorphism, Kernel and Image

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f$ the homomorphism $f: (\mathbb{Z},+)\to S_6, f(1)=(123)(456).$ Find the Kernel and image of $f$.

Hello, my question is how solve this $(123)(456)$? In form matrix, because can to be $(123)(456)=\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\       
   2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 4 \      
\end{array} } \right]$? Correct?

Comment: Yes, the matrix form is correct. Can you find $f(2) = f(1 + 1)$?

Answer (score 1):

as the matrix notation of a permutation is correct, to find kernel
and Image of the group homomorphism $f$; we note that    1 is the
generator of $\Bbb{Z}$, so $f (1) = (123)(456)$ is a generator of
$ Imf$ that is cyclic of order 3 because $(123)(456)$ has order 3
as product of two disjoint 3-cycle,  it follows that the kernel is
$3\Bbb{Z}$.